# How to split a line with available format using python?

Tags: string, python-2.7, filter

I have a line in file with content follow available format:

"hello python" "stackoverflow"

I want to split it into two string separately such as:

String 1: hello python

String 2: stackoverflow

I can do that by using split letter by letter and connect them together but it's quite complicated.
Please give me solution!

Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

```
a = '"hello python" "stackoverflow"'
b = [e for e in a.split('"') if len(e.strip()) > 0]
print(b[0], b[1]) # ('hello python', 'stackoverflow')
```

String 1 is b[0]

String 2 is b[1]

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import re
cons = "String"
input = r'"text1""text2" "text3"'
result = re.findall('"[^"]+"', input)
print(result)
for i in range(len(result)):
    print (cons + str(i) + ':' + result[i])
```